# The operator '+' isn't defined for the type 'Object'. T

Tags: flutter, dart

When I try to add a list of doubles i get

> The operator '+' isn't defined for the type 'Object'. T

flutter channel stable 2.0.5 was working fine on flutter stable 1.22.6

```
 List<double>? totalDiscount = [];
var total = totalDiscount.fold(
        0, (previousValue, element) => previousValue! + element);
```

Comment: Try setting the output type like this `totalDiscount.fold<double>(...)`.

Comment: Nice. Good luck!